# What actually happens when I modify AWS EBS type and it is in optimizing status

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I read this [AWS EBS Volume "in-use - optimizing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43771207/aws-ebs-volume-in-use-optimizing) and  learned that volume performance would be in between the source and target configuration specifications.

My question is, when I change the EBS type (for example from `gp2` to `io1`) and it is in a state of `optimizing`, is EBS actually synchronizing data to a new EBS, or is EBS just 
 originally the type with the best performance, which limited its type and performance (like CPU) (with no data syncing)?

The same question arises when `io1` types change IOPS.

Answer (score 0):

When you migrate the EBS volume between EBS type it is synchronising the data between and keeping them in-sync. You will always maintain at least the minimums IOPs for its performance.

Its also of worth noting that there are [multiple copies of the volume](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/features/#Amazon_EBS_availability_and_durability) stored in the AZ, which means its not just synchronizing from 1 volume to another.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you think it used different EBS types or the same EBS type when making copies for high availability?